# Efficient graph search with brute force

Tags: performance, data-structures, graph, computer-science, brute-force

I could not think of a better title.

My problem is this:

I have a list of symbols and  each of them is tagged with at least one classification (some of them could have more).

Let's say that I have 4 symbols: [[1,2], 1, 1, 1,] -> the first one can be classified as 1 or 2 and the other 3 are always classified as 1 (instead of numbers you could think of strings such as 'human', 'animal' and so on).

I have some "rules" that can merge symbols and generate new ones. This process generate a graph. In the example above, I have 2 initial states:
[1,1,1,1] and [2,1,1,1] and if I apply some rules on them I obtain 2 distinct graphs (rules such as unify an 1 with an 1 if, or a 2 with an 1 if and so on...).

One solution could be to apply every rule to every initial state and generate the final graph, but I was thinking that some part of the graph could potentially be the same and I would end up recomputing the same thing more than once.

For example, if I have [[1,2,3], 1,....long part disjoint from the previous one], maybe the only differences in these graphs is only on the left part, but the right one is always the same (with a brute force approach, I would always recompute it).

**Could you think of a clever way to not recompute the same portion of the graph? Does this problem I have remember you about something that I could read?**